# Is there a way in ReSharper to suppress all errors/warnings in one file?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a number of generated .cs files (originating from WSTL files).  ReSharper isn't happy and I'm getting so many errors/warnings that its tough to separate the signal from the noise.

Is there a way to work around this?  Can I suppress all the warnings/errors in an easy way?

My goal is to keep from (or minimize) changes to the generated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to mark code as generated in Resharper [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Generated_Code.html) explain them all but i guess that for your case changing the name of the files to match the default `*.generated.cs` would be the simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Turn code analysis on/off  =>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>  (with Visual Studio key bindings; otherwise it could just be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> )

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+8 works since ReSharper 5; earlier it was Ctrl+8